# C++ subclass parameterized class, and use the subclass as a specialization

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want something like this:

```
class TestParent<class T>
{
    T* some();
}

class TestChild : public TestParent<TestChild>
{};
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you've meant `template <class T> class TestParent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but only if you define an implementation of `some` otherwise you'll be confronted by compilation errors.  You may also want to add a protected constructor so that your base class can't be created and used outside of how you define it in your header scope.

```
template<typename T>
class TestParent{
    public:

        T* some() { return new T(); }

    //this is suggested
    protected:
        TestParent(){}
};

class TestChild : public TestParent<TestChild>{}
```

This is used in the [curiously recuring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and other techniques from [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) made popular by Alexandrescu's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315).

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely!  This technique is often used in advanced techniques like [the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or to implement [static polymorphism](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?StaticPolymorphism).  You'll see it a lot if you do advanced C++ programming.